# Redirect to same page after successful submission of a form and clicking OK on a confirmation message

Tags: javascript, php

I'm using insert.php file to connect to the db, insert the user's request, send a success confirmation message then redirect user to the same page. This is the code:

```
if (!mysqli_query ($db_conx, $sql)) {
    die ('Error: ' . mysqli_error($db_conx));
} 
else {
echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
echo 'alert("Thank you! Your request has been successfully sent.")';
echo '</script>';
}

header ('Location:http://www.mywebsite.com.au/page1.php');
mysqli_close ($db_conx);
```

The problem is that after the user clicks on "OK" on the confirmation alert box the page moves from page1 to insert.php with a blank white screen. 
I want to refresh the page1 page and stay on it.

Comment: I'm not really understanding what you want. If you "refresh page1 and stay on it" it would never do the code on insert.php. If I understand correctly, what you are looking for is AJAX? Or, you could just make the insert.php page redirect back to page1?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton All I need is to redirect back to page1 after the insert.php file finishes its tasks, which are connecting to the db, inserting data to db, show the confirmation message box then close the db. I don't think I need AJAX to do the job. It should be simple and straightforward

Comment: If you have echoed anything out to the user (such as your script with the alert), then the headers have already been sent, and you can no longer modify them with the `header()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    if (!mysqli_query ($db_conx, $sql)) {
        die ('Error: ' . mysqli_error($db_conx));
    } 
    else {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
        echo 'alert("Thank you! Your request has been successfully sent.")';
        echo '</script>';
    }
    mysqli_close ($db_conx);
    echo "<META http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=page1.php\">";
```

I could personally never get `header` to work properly for me either, but `meta refresh` has always worked the way I needed it to.

In my snippet, I use `meta refresh` and tell it to wait for **0** seconds (`content=\"0;`) before it redirects to the page1.php page (`;URL=page1.php\"`), that way there it will redirect directly after the user hits "Okay" on the alert message.

Alternatively, you can put in a confirmation message that does NOT need user interaction on the insert.php page, and you can can change the redirect time to something like 2 or 3 so the user has a chance to see it.

Comment: @DanaAchrafi If you get an answer that correctly answers your question, you should click the check mark under the arrows on the left side, this shows that the correct answer was found. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
if (!mysqli_query ($db_conx, $sql)) {
    die ('Error: ' . mysqli_error($db_conx));
} 
else {
echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
echo 'alert("Thank you! Your request has been successfully sent.")';
echo 'window.location.href = "http://www.mywebsite.com.au/page1.php"';  
echo '</script>';

 mysqli_close ($db_conx);
}
```

Comment: I tried this previously but it didn't even show the message box! It just took me to the insert.php page (empty white screen)

Answer (score -1):

Please use this code:

```
if (!mysqli_query ($db_conx, $sql)) {
   die ('Error: ' . mysqli_error($db_conx));
} 
else {
   echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
   echo 'alert("Thank you! Your request has been successfully sent.")';
   echo '</script>';
}

mysqli_close ($db_conx);

// Use Location: not Location : , that means now space between Location and :(colon)
header ('Location: http://www.mywebsite.com.au/page1.php');
```

Comment: Use what ? why ? How your code is different from the one OP ha s provided ?

Comment: no @ahossain, this didn't work. I already don't have a space between Location and its colon. I tried moving the statement to be located after closing the database but nothing changed.